# Convert Javascript Reduce Function to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, entity-framework, jsonresult

I am trying to convert this function from Javascript to C#. 
The goal is to receive a List of contracts and sort them into subgroups, bundling them if they have the same client.

```
> let c1 = {id:1,name:"c1"} 
> let c2 = {id:2,name:"c2"} 
> let c3 =  {id:2,name:"c3"} 
> let c4 = {id:1,name:"c4"} 
> let c5 = {id:3,name:"c5"}
> let list = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]
> 
> const groupByKey = (array, property) => {   return
> array.reduce((accumulator, object) => {
>     const key = object[property];
> 
>     if (!accumulator[key]) {
>       accumulator[key] = []
>     }
>     accumulator[key].push(object)
>     return accumulator;   }, {}) }
> 
> groupByKey(list, "id") 
> 
> // input = let list = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5] //output =
> {"1":[{"id":1,"name":"c1"},{"id":1,"name":"c4"}],"2":[{"id":2,"name":"c2"},{"id":2,"name":"c3"}],"3":[{"id":3,"name":"c5"}]}
```

// preferebly the output would be a list of Lists containting the contracts bundled.

Update:
I have written the function the problem is that i need to return just the contracts ids, not the whole object.

```
desired output [[c1.id,c4.id],[c2.id,c3.id],[c5.id]]
```

This is what i currently have.

```
        public JsonResult checkForSameClient(long[] listOfContracts)
        {
// here i grab the list of contracts ids then go to my repository and find //the whole objects to be compared.






IQueryable<ContratEspace> contrats = contratEspaceRepository.Get(1, listOfContracts.Count(), listOfContracts);
                var contratList = contrats.ToList();

            var finalArray = contrats.GroupBy(c => c.id_clientGestion).ToList();
            return new JsonResult() { Data = finalArray };
        }
```

But this is not returning the Json.Data correctly im having the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fromJson (angular.js:1282)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (angular.js:10133)
    at angular.js:10224
    at forEach (angular.js:321)
    at transformData (angular.js:10223)
    at transformResponse (angular.js:10996)
    at processQueue (angular.js:15552)
    at angular.js:15568
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The .NET counterpart to javascript `array.reduce(...)` is `Enumerable.Aggregate(...)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: ive tried to convert to .Aggregate but couldnt make it work the same way.

Also, trying the GroupBy() to try and simplify.

I wrote a nested loop with vanilla syntax, but its not giving me the output desired.

Comment: The new syntax error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` should not be related to `GroupBy(...)`. For some reasnon, json is not returned from your call to the backend controller. It may be that the controller crashes with some exception, and some generic error page is returned. If possible, try to call the backend controller method from Chrome or some other web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since GroupBy is built in .NET it is not necessary to write the aggregate function.

How to group a list in C#:

```
var list = new [] {
   new { Id = 1, Name = "c1"},
   new { Id = 2, Name = "c2"},
   new { Id = 2, Name = "c3"},
   new { Id = 1, Name = "c4"},
   new { Id = 3, Name = "c5"},
};

var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
```

The lambda function `x => x.Id` may be tailored to fit your needs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1